# Ошибка: expected initializer before 'PointType'

Tags: c++, linux

В данном куске кода:

```
PointType *createPoint(int x, int y, int value){
    PointType* vertex =(PointType*)malloc(sizeof(PointType));
    vertex -> x = x;
    vertex -> y = y;
    vertex -> value = value;
    return vertex;
}
```

Возникает ошибка:

```
main.cpp:29:1: error: expected initializer before 'PointType'
PointType *createPoint(int x, int y, int value){
^
```

Сама структура выглядит так:

```
typedef struct Point PointType;
struct Point{
    int x;
    int y;
    int value;
};
```

В чём может заключаться данная проблема?

Comment: Нет тут никакой проблемы. Возможно, точка с запятой выше где-то пропущена или скобки непарные.

Comment: В С++ следует использовать new/delete вместо malloc/free

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4):

К такой ошибке приводит обычно пропущенная точка с запятой.

Посмотрите кусок кода непосредственно перед проблемной строкой. Если перед ней стоит `#include`, загляните в конец header'а (`#include` тупо включает текст  header'а в точке, где он упомянут).

Этот кусок кода — определение класса или структуры, не забудьте, что в C++ оно тоже должно оканчиваться точкой с запятой. То же самое насчёт предварительных объявлений функций и глобальных переменных, но в таких местах обычно ошибаются реже.

Пример:

(x.h)

```
#ifndef X_H
#define X_H

double variable // <-- пропущена точка с запятой тут

#endif
```

(x.cpp)

```
#include "x.h"

PointType *createPoint(int x, int y, int value) { // <-- ошибка будет сообщена здесь
    // ...
```

Пруф: http://ideone.com/KHT4pz